# Inno Setup Disable checkbox

Tags: inno-setup

Как отключить checkbox : "создать ярлык на рабочем столе" ?

Answer (score 2):

Обычно ярлык на рабочем столе делают через такски.
Примерно так:

```
[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon
```

Флаг таска `unchecked` говорит компилятору сделать чекбокс по умолчанию не выбранным. Если вы хотите совсем убрать этот чекбокс из инсталлятора, то нужно удалить этот таск из раздела `[Tasks]` и убрать создание соответствующего ярлыка из раздела `[Icons]`.